# How update a config file with a bash script?

Tags: bash, httpd.conf

When launching an AWS EC2 instance you can specify User Data.
I would like to create a bash script that automatically updates the file **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** like follow:

Update 1:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    ### Original content ###
 
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php    # ← Add
</IfModule>
```

Update 2:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    ### Original content ###
 
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    # AllowOverride None    # ← Before
    AllowOverride All    # ← Update
 
    ### Original content ###
</Directory>
```

How to do that ? And what do you think is the best way to do that?
I don't know bash well enough so I'm considering using the php command to do that (**php -r**). Is it a bad idea?

Regards

Edit: this is the php command

```
#!/bin/bash

php -r '$filename = "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf";
$content = file_get_contents($filename);    

$pattern = "/<IfModule mime_module>([\S\s]*?)<\/IfModule>/";
preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
$matches[1] = "<IfModule mime_module>\n$matches[1]    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php\n</IfModule>"; 
$content = str_replace($matches[0], $matches[1], $content);

$pattern = "/<Directory \"\/var\/www\/html\">([\S\s]*?)<\/Directory>/";
preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
$matches[1] = str_replace("AllowOverride None", "AllowOverride All", $matches[1]); 
$content = "<Directory \"/var/www/html\">".str_replace($matches[0], $matches[1], $content)."</Directory>";

file_put_contents($filename, $content);';
```

I want to do the same thing without php command (only with bash script)

Comment: Are those updates fixed? What's the structure of the conf file? Are those updates done in a sequence or all at once?

Comment: Is a change of ```httpd.conf ``` triggered by the webserver? I guess the server needs a restart after configuration change

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi 「Is a change of httpd.conf  triggered by the webserver?」No. after the php command there is a "service httpd restart"

Answer (score 2):

Override the whole httpd.conf file. It is easier and faster